# 0x API returning error for getting Fantom quote

Tags: decentralized-exchange, 0x, swaps, fantom

The call is this one and fails with a "Server Error"

https://fantom.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?&buyToken=0x04068da6c83afcfa0e13ba15a6696662335d5b75&sellToken=0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE&sellAmount=1000000000000000000&skipValidation=true&slippagePercentage=0.01

Comment: Seems like the error got rid of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me ‍♂️

An *Internal Server Error* here, as you saw, is the result of the 0x servers failing for whatever reason. Could be over-loaded servers, down for maintenance, etc.
Sometimes that happens. Just try the request again.